# HTML5/CSS3 Within an iPad App (No Javascript)

Tags: ios, ipad, html, css

I'm going to be working on some HTML5/CSS3 that will be included in an iPad app and I liked this [example](http://www.jonathan-krause.de/rainforest) for the subtle changes. I don't know too much about some of the limitations on an iPad when html5/css3 content is included within a native app, but is all of possible as just html/css3? Or do I need javascript?

Comment: That page does use jquery and other javacript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS uses Webkit for displaying HTML content. Hence you can easily test your HTML, CSS and JavaScript stuff either in Safari.app on your device, the iOS simulator or in a simple app which just has a UIwebView in it.

I don't know if you could realise an HTML page like your example without JavaScript (I know that CSS3 has some support for animations. However, even if you need JavaScript this should be a problem when building an iOS app.